# Executing a program (rdiff) from PHP

Tags: php, permissions, exec

I have this PHP code that refuses to work when called from the browser, but **when I run it from Putty it works just fine**:

```
exec('rdiff patch "/full-path/file-1.bin" "/full-path/file-2.bin" "/full-path/output.bin"');
```

I double checked folder permission (nobody:nobody 0777), rdiff running permissions (set to root:root 0755, I changed them to nobody:nobody 0777 but it didn't work), I even changed files permissions to 0777 / "CHOWNed them" to nobody, it didn't work at all

I'm pretty sure it's nothing, only I can't figure out what's wrong, **I'm using a standard amazon unix EC2 instance**

Comment: *"code that refuses to work"* is not a well description of the problem you face. I suggest you improve your question to get better answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rdiff` may very well not be in the `PATH` for the user the web server is running as.

Always use the full path to executables when not running them interactively, e.g. `/usr/bin/rdiff` or whatever `which rdiff` tells you in PuTTY.